# StarCraft2: how can Terran wall-in if choke exit is on the right bottom side?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-terran

If choke exit is on the right bottom side then Terran's wall-in barrack can't build reactor/techlab... In this case if you plan to go 1-1-1 strategy you won't be able to build techlab/reactor as your barrack is very close to unbuildable surface...

What is suggestion for such cases?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are going for Technology, you might want to consider to place a Bunker after you lift your Rax.

Scouting is key to determine if it's necessary to spent effort on getting a tight wall...

Comment: bunker is too week replacement for barrack...

Comment: @Budda: If your wall has a Supply Depot, then why do the life points of a Barracks still matter? A Bunker has the same life points as a Supply Depot so is a completely valid replacement. It is useful as it serves as armor for your housed units, closes the wall and provides your housed units with additional range...

Comment: Agree.. The also additional point that I get from replays: PRO players build wall very late... instead of wall they push opponent with marines/marauders...

Comment: @Budda: Yeah, Terran can destroy the wall (and more) with good Tank play, and Protoss can blink with Stalkers. I often see Diamond Terran players (on eg. Metalolis), create three buildings next to each other so that it forms a passage. That way you have to run around all three buildings and back to get to the mineral line....

Answer (score 4):

Generally players will create a tight wall off with there naked barracks (no add-ons) and once they are ready to build a tech lab or reactor they will lift off the barracks and land it with enough space (add-on facing the ramp).

While this is more vulnerable then other spawn positions where your add-on is on the other side of the barracks, it still provides you with a tight wall off and is better than nothing.

Specifically in the 1-1-1 build you mentioned.  Because there is so much add-on switching going on, it is possible to have either your factory or starport (depending on what units you go) building your extra add-ons.  Most players also throw down a second barracks shortly after as well (which can also help build add-ons)

Comment: Naked barracks - the only option to wall-in in this case. But it can be an option if you go to Mega Rax build. If you do 1-1-1, you can't build the 2nd rax (actually, you can, but that will delay medivac/raven/banshee). Instead, I would like to have my 1st barrack with reactor, and once factory build, I will pick rax to new place (for building tech-lab) and connect factory to reactor to get quick Helions. So, Aardvark, thank you for idea, but is not an answer on question. It seems like your answer is: "you can't build add-on? then just don't build them". but thank you anyway.

Comment: In my comment I wanted to write: "it can NOT be an option..." (and later in text I've tried to use reactor of the 1st barrack for factory)

Comment: @Budda That's not what I said at all.  I said when building your first barracks, place it tightly in the wall as if your intention was not to build the addon.  When you build your addon, lift your rax fly it 2 squares over and land it building your addon facing the ramp, this will assure a solid wall-in and allow you to build your addon

Answer (score 2):

I often wall in with my first Supply Depot and Barracks at the bottom of the ramp. So long as you place the depot on the correct side, you should always be able to build an add-on without blocking where you'd place a Command Centre at your natural. This will usually prevent a worker from scouting whether you took your gas. Other times their scouting worker will get trapped inside your base, which at least ensures you can kill it. Make sure you're ready to defend the SCV building the Barracks.